# Is there a way to override the theme of WidgetKit, so that we can retrieve correct named color in WidgetKit?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

In main app, I can override dark/ light theme based on user preference, so that I can retrieve correct color information based on named color.

```
if (user preference) {
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
} else {
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
}


// Dark theme/ light theme automatic aware color.
SwiftUI.Color("purpleColor")
```

However, how can I override the theme of a `WidgetKit`, so that my `WidgetKit` can interpret named color correctly?

I know in `WidgetKit`, I can read what is current system wide theme settings using `@Environment(\.colorScheme)`.

But, that is not what I want.

I want the ability to **override** theme of a `WidgetKit` based on user preference, then able to retrieve correct named color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `.colorScheme` on a view by view basis. The simplest way is using a ternary and inject the new `.colorScheme` into the view If you want to change the device `.colorScheme` use `.preferredColorScheme`:

```
struct ColorSchemeView: View {
    
    @State var deviceIsDark = false
    @State var viewIsDark = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.purple
                .overlay(
                Text("Change Device ColorScheme")
                )
                .preferredColorScheme(deviceIsDark ? .dark : .light)
                .onTapGesture {
                    deviceIsDark.toggle()
                }
            
            Color.purple
                .overlay(
                Text("Change View ColorScheme")
                )
                .environment(\.colorScheme, viewIsDark ? .dark : .light)
                .onTapGesture {
                    viewIsDark.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Oh, and it is unnecessary to use SwiftUI. That will be assumed.